# Decision path for Azure Service Fabric Programming Models

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

**Background**

We are looking at porting a 'monolithic' 3 tier Web app to a microservices architecture. The web app displays listings to a consumer (think Craiglist).

The backend consists of a REST API that calls into a SQL DB and returns JSON for a SPA app to build a UI (there's also a mobile app). Data is written to the SQL DB via background services (ftp + worker roles). There's also some pages that allow writes by the user.

**Information required:**

I'm trying to figure out how (if at all), Azure Service Fabric would be a good fit for a microservices architecture in my scenario. I know the pros/cons of microservices vs monolith, but i'm trying to figure out the *application* of various microservice programming models to our current architecture.

**Questions**

- Is Azure Service Fabric a good fit for this? If not, other recommendations? Currently i'm leaning towards a bunch of OWIN-based .NET web sites, split up by area/service, each hosted on their own machine and tied together by an API gateway.
- Which Service Fabric programming model would i go for? Stateless services with their own backing DB? I can't see how Stateful or Actor model would help here.
- If i went with Stateful services/Actor, how would i go about updating data as part of a maintenance/ad-hoc admin request? Traditionally we would simply login to the DB and update the data, and the API would return the new data - but if it's persisted in-memory/across nodes in a cluster, how would we update it? Would i have to expose this all via methods on the service? Similarly, how would I import my existing SQL data into a stateful service?
- For Stateful services/actor model, how can I 'see' the data visually, with an object Explorer/UI. Our data is our Gold, and I'm concerned of the lack of control/visibility of it in the reliable services models

Basically, is there some documentation on the *decision path* towards which programming model to go for? I could model a "listing" as an Actor, and have millions of those - sure, but i could also have a Stateful service that stores the listing locally, and i could also have a Stateless service that fetches it from the DB. How does one decide as to which is the best approach, for a given use case?

Thanks.

Comment: About the service fabric vs web apps look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615381/advantages-of-service-fabric-microservices-vs-collection-of-azure-cloud-services/40139417#40139417

Comment: To answer the other questions: 2) it depends 3) you have to write code to provide access to the data 4) there is nothing for it yet.

Comment: Your question is really really broad, maybe start with just trying out ASF. Using the sdk you can develop on your local machine cluster. Get some feeling of it and try some samples.

Comment: @Peter Bons thanks for the comments. I have tried the samples, and I thought I was missing something, but your comments have confirmed I haven't. I think not having transparency /visibility/management  of the data is a deal breaker for me for stateful services/actor model. Can I ask why I would chose stateless services interacting with an external DB in ASF over just doing the same with a Web app? Is the only benefit gained from a Dev ops perspective? (DR, HA, deployment etc) and not so much performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it about your current setup that isn't meeting your requirements? What do you hope to gain from a more complex architecture?

Microservices aren't a magic bullet. You mainly get four benefits:

1. You can scale and distribute pieces of your overall system independently. Service Fabric has *very* sophisticated tools and advanced capabilities for this.
2. You can deploy and upgrade pieces of your overall system independently. Service Fabric again has advanced capabilities for this.
3. You can have a polyglot system - each service can be written in a different language/platform.
4. You can use conflicting dependencies - each service can have its own set of dependencies, like different framework versions.

All of this comes at a cost and introduces complexity and new ways your system can fail. For example: your fast, compile-time checked in-proc method calls now become  slow (by comparison to an in-proc function call) failure-prone network calls. And these are **not** specific to Service Fabric, btw, this is just what happens you go from in-proc method calls to cross-machine I/O - doesn't matter what platform you use. The *decision path* here is a pro/con list specific to your application and your requirements.

To answer your Service Fabric questions specifically:

- Which programming model do you go for? Start with stateless services with ASP.NET Core. It's going to be the simplest translation of your current architecture that doesn't require mucking around with your data layer.
- Stateful has a lot of great uses, but it's not necessarily a replacement for your RDBMS. A good place to start is hot data that can be stored in simple key-value pairs, is accessed frequently and needs to be low-latency (you get local reads!), and doesn't need to be datamined. Some examples include user session state, cache data, a "snapshot" of the most recent items in a data stream (like the most recent stock quote in a stream of stock quotes).
- Currently the only way to see or query your data is programmatically directly against the Reliable Collection APIs. There is no viewer or "management studio" tool. You have to write (and secure) an API in each service that can display and query data.
- Finally, the actor model is a *very* niche model. It serves specific purposes but if you just treat it as a data store it will not work for you. Like in your example, a listing per actor probably wouldn't work because you can't query across that list, or even have multiple users reading the same listing simultaneously.

Comment: Perfect answer, thankyou :) Any chance you could help out/provide guidance on a multi-sln setup? I raised an issue: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/issues/30 I also have another stack Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234830/single-service-fabric-application-referencing-multiple-external-web-apis Not sure whether raising an issue or asking another Q was the right way :) thanks again!

Comment: you'll probably get a better response on stackoverflow for that question, I'll check it out there. Glad I could help!