# What are the advantages of using a Service Fabric stateless service over a Cloud Service Worker Role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to understand the advantages of using Service Fabric over a cloud service worker role.

Currently, I am using a cloud service for hosting (web role and worker role).

Will there be any advantage if I change the cloud service to an App Service Web app for hosting the web role and a Service Fabric stateless service for hosting the worker role? If so, what are the advantages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of Service Fabric Microservices vs Collection of Azure Cloud services/web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615381/advantages-of-service-fabric-microservices-vs-collection-of-azure-cloud-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PRADEEP CHEEKATLA said,Service Fabric itself is an **application platform layer** that runs on Windows or Linux, whereas Cloud Services is a **system** for deploying Azure-managed VMs with workloads attached.

> In Cloud Services, a Worker Role VM hosts one workload. In Service Fabric, applications are separate from the VMs that run them, meaning you can deploy a large number of applications to a small number of VMs, which can lower overall cost for larger deployments.

And the [key difference between Service Fabric and Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-differences) is that in **Cloud Services you connect to a VM**, whereas in **Service Fabric you connect to a service**.

This is an important distinction for a couple reasons:

1.Services in Service Fabric are not bound to the VMs that host them; services may move around in the cluster, and in fact, are expected to move around for various reasons: Resource balancing, failover, application and infrastructure upgrades, and placement or load constraints. This means a service instance's address can change at any time.

2.A VM in Service Fabric can host multiple services, each with unique endpoints.

Here is a [comparing Cloud Services with Service Fabric](https://github.com/mspnp/architecture-center/blob/master/docs/service-fabric/migrate-from-cloud-services.md)：
[image]

Also, you could refer to this article to [converting Web and Worker Roles to Service Fabric stateless services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service).

Answer (score 2):

Service Fabric itself is an application platform layer that runs on Windows or Linux, whereas Cloud Services is a system for deploying Azure-managed VMs with workloads attached. The Service Fabric application model has a number of advantages:

- Fast deployment times. Creating VM instances can be time consuming. In Service Fabric, VMs are only deployed once to form a cluster that hosts the Service Fabric application platform. From that point on, application packages can be deployed to the cluster very quickly.
- High-density hosting. In Cloud Services, a Worker Role VM hosts one workload. In Service Fabric, applications are separate from the VMs that run them, meaning you can deploy a large number of applications to a small number of VMs, which can lower overall cost for larger deployments.
- The Service Fabric platform can run anywhere that has Windows Server or Linux machines, whether it's Azure or on-premises. The platform provides an abstraction layer over the underlying infrastructure so your application can run on different environments.
- Distributed application management. Service Fabric is a platform that not only hosts distributed applications, but also helps manage their lifecycle independently of the hosting VM or machine lifecycle.

For more details, refer "[Learn about the differences between Cloud Services and Service Fabric before migrating applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-differences)".

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) helps you understand the options and make the right choice for your web application.